# ftp_rawlist(): bind() failed: Permission denied (13)

Tags: php, ftp, server

How to get ftp_raw_list working on ipage webhosting? 
Here's the code:

```
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

// get the file list for /
$buff = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, '/');

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

// output the buffer
var_dump($buff);
```

When I run this code in server with php 5.3.13 it shows this output:

```
bool(false)
```

But it works totally fine on localhost returning 26 arrays. FTP server, username, password details are accurate as well, because they are working from local host. I just didn't put those details here.

When I checked the CGI Error Logs, it showed this error:

```
ftp_rawlist(): bind() failed: Permission denied (13)
```

After that I changed the file permissions in filezilla to 777, but nothing changed, and when I changed the folder's permissions to 777, the file stopped running, and it was showing this error:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

When I contacted the support team of my hosting, this is what they said:

"In our platform the permission for the folders is ‘755’ and that for the files is ‘644’ "

Is there anyway to fix this problem than dumping the hosting service which I can't afford at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($login_result){
      $buff = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, '/');
}
else
    echo "NO CONNECTION";
```

Check it.

Comment: Thanks Maiti, I did that and it's still showing bool(false) output.  I just checked error log, and it says: 

"ftp_rawlist(): bind() failed: Permission denied (13)"

After that I changed the file permissions in filezilla to 777, but nothing changed, and when I changed the folder's permissions to 777, the file stopped running, and it was showing this error:

"500 Internal Server Error"

When I contacted the support team of my hosting, this is what they said:

"In our platform the permission for the folders is ‘755’ and that for the files is ‘644’. I have reset the files permissions. "